# JVZoo: Pay Now / Checkout button

Tags: ecommerce, paypal, payments, payment-gateway, checkout

I just want to know if it is possible to use JVZoo as a payment processor on my website (like PayPal, 2checkout, etc.) Or is it just for affiliate based sales creation?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this forum](http://www.warriorforum.com/main-internet-marketing-discussion-forum/682070-using-jvzoo-payment-processor.html), JVZoo is not a payment processor, it is just a payment gateway that uses PayPal behind the scenes.

> JVZoo is not a payment processor. Without a payment processor such as Paypal, it wouldn't do anything. It relies on Paypal to process the payments.